# How to customise an XML export using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

For testing purposes, I used used JAXB to generate an XML from an Object. This work fine. The code is below.

```
    package com.mns.mnsutilities.jaxb.model;

    import java.util.List;


    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

    @XmlRootElement(name="Emp_MNS")
    @XmlType(propOrder= {"name", "age", "role", "gender", "addressesList"})
    public class Employee {
        private int id;
        private String gender;
        private int age;
        private String name;
        private String role;
        private String password;
        private List<Address> addressesList;

        public Employee() {}

        public Employee(int id, String gender, int age, String name, String role,
                String password) {
            super();
            this.id = id;
            this.gender = gender;
            this.age = age;
            this.name = name;
            this.role = role;
            this.password = password;
        }

        public Employee(int id, String gender, int age, String name, String role,
                String password, List<Address> addressesList) {
            super();
            this.id = id;
            this.gender = gender;
            this.age = age;
            this.name = name;
            this.role = role;
            this.password = password;
            this.addressesList = addressesList;
        }

        @XmlAttribute
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        @XmlElement(name = "gen")
        public String getGender() {
            return gender;
        }
        public void setGender(String gender) {
            this.gender = gender;
        }
        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }
        public void setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }
       // @XmlNullPolicy(emptyNodeRepresentsNull = true, nullRepresentationForXml = XmlMarshalNullRepresentation.EMPTY_NODE)
        @XmlElement(nillable=true)
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getRole() {
            return role;
        }
        public void setRole(String role) {
            this.role = role;
        }
        @XmlTransient
        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }
        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }
        @XmlElement(name = "addresses")
        public List<Address> getAddressesList() {
            return addressesList;
        }

        public void setAddressesList(List<Address> addressesList) {
            this.addressesList = addressesList;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Employee [id=" + id + ", gender=" + gender + ", age=" + age
                    + ", name=" + name + ", role=" + role + ", password="
                    + password + ", addressesList=" + addressesList + "]";
        }
    }
```

And:

```
    package com.mns.mnsutilities.jaxb.model;

    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


    @XmlRootElement(namespace="")
    public class Address {
        private String street;
        private String city;
        private String zipCode;
        private String country;

        public Address() {}

        public Address(String street, String city, String zipCode, String country) {
            super();
            this.street = street;
            this.city = city;
            this.zipCode = zipCode;
            this.country = country;
        }

        public String getStreet() {
            return street;
        }

        public void setStreet(String street) {
            this.street = street;
        }

        public String getCity() {
            return city;
        }

        public void setCity(String city) {
            this.city = city;
        }

        public String getZipCode() {
            return zipCode;
        }

        public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
            this.zipCode = zipCode;
        }

        public String getCountry() {
            return country;
        }

        public void setCountry(String country) {
            this.country = country;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Address [street=" + street + ", city=" + city + ", zipCode="
                    + zipCode + ", country=" + country + "]";
        }

    }
```

My main Class is :

```
    package com.mns.mnsutilities.jaxb.batch;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
    import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
    import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
    import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

    import com.mns.mnsutilities.jaxb.model.Address;
    import com.mns.mnsutilities.jaxb.model.Employee;

    public class LaunchAction {
        private static final String FILE_NAME = "output/CT3D_XML_SAMPLE_FINAL.xml";

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Employee emp = new Employee();
            emp.setId(1);
            emp.setAge(25);
            emp.setName("Yovan");
            emp.setGender("Male");
            emp.setRole("Developer");
            emp.setPassword("sensitive");
            List<Address> addressesList = new ArrayList<>();
            Address address1 = new Address("Main Road", "Ebene", "11111", "Mauritius");
            Address address2 = new Address("Royal Road", "Rose-Hill", "2222", "Mauritius");
            addressesList.add(address1);
            addressesList.add(address2);
            emp.setAddressesList(addressesList);

            jaxbObjectToXML(emp);


            Employee empFromFile = jaxbXMLToObject();
            System.out.println(empFromFile.toString());
        }


        private static Employee jaxbXMLToObject() {
            try {
                JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employee.class);
                Unmarshaller un = context.createUnmarshaller();
                Employee emp = (Employee) un.unmarshal(new File(FILE_NAME));
                return emp;
            } catch (JAXBException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }


        private static void jaxbObjectToXML(Employee emp) {

            try {
                JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employee.class);
                Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
                //for pretty-print XML in JAXB
                m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

                // Write to System.out for debugging
                 m.marshal(emp, System.out);

                // Write to File
                m.marshal(emp, new File(FILE_NAME));
            } catch (JAXBException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }
```

The XML output is :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <Emp_MNS id="1">
        <name xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true">
        </name>
        <age>25</age>
        <role>Developer</role>
        <gen>Juggoo</gen>
        <addresses>
            <city>Ebene</city>
            <country>Mauritius</country>
            <street>Main Road</street>
            <zipCode>11111</zipCode>
        </addresses>
        <addresses>
            <city>Rose-Hill</city>
            <country>Mauritius</country>
            <street>Royal Road</street>
            <zipCode>2222</zipCode>
        </addresses>
    </Emp_MNS>
```

What I really would like to have is :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <Emp_MNS id="1">
        <name xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true">
        </name>
        <age>25</age>
        <role>Developer</role>
        <gen>Juggoo</gen>
        <addresses>
            **<address>** 
                <city>Ebene</city>
                <country>Mauritius</country>
                <street>Main Road</street>
                <zipCode>11111</zipCode>
            **</address>** 
            **<address>**
                <city>Rose-Hill</city>
                <country>Mauritius</country>
                <street>Royal Road</street>
                <zipCode>2222</zipCode>
            **</address>**
        </addresses>
    </Emp_MNS>
```

Could you please guide me on how to proceed?

Comment: Something like [this](https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_6_2_7_7-Wrapping-Repeated-Elements-XmlElementWrapper.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="addresses")
@XmlElement(name="address")
public List<Address> getAddressesList() {
```

Comment: Hi Blaise. I think I came accross a tutorial you posted somewhere. Could you please guide me on any good books on manipulating XML in Java?

Comment: @yovan786 - I don't have any book recommendations, but I try to make my blog as useful as possible for Java and XML issues related to object-binding:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/